# Replacing a line segment with smaller segments

Tags: algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

Problem to be solved:
How can a line segment of length L(a stick) be replaced by instances of two types of smaller line segments(two types of sticks), one of which is red and the other one is blue.

Constraints:

1. Red stick has some constant length equal to 1000 units.
2. Blue stick has a variable length B(B should be >= 200 and <= 1000 in all cases).
3. The distance between two blue sticks should be <= 3000.
4. Number of blue sticks < number of red sticks

Also, the length of most of the blue sticks should be as close to 200 as possible.

[image: Look at the image for illustration]

The best solution will be two of 200 and one of 600.

The length in this case is 5000 units, which may vary depending on the problem(but will always be a multiple of 50).

Comment: Question formulation looks weird and unclear. Could you describe real problem?

Comment: That paragraph after the bullets is confusing me somewhat.  Yes, please give a specific example or two, things to illustrate the trade-offs.

Comment: RBRB... or RRBRRB... sequences fulfill given requirements. But seems you want something different. What to do with B lengths? `Blue stick has length B` - constant? `length of most of the blue sticks should be very close to each other` - vary?

Comment: The length of blue stick can vary between 200 and 1000. For example one blue stick can have length equal to 300, the other one can have length 900.

Comment: If L is more than 2000, lay down Red sticks until the space left is less than 2000. If the space left is <= 1000, cover it with one Blue stick, otherwise cover it with two Blue sticks of equal length. Am I missing something?